# Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на стрелку вверх или вниз число счетчика менялось, и был активен нужный этаж на чистом js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, count, toggle

Задача следующем: при клике на стрелку вверх или вниз, число счетчика должно или прибавлятся на 1 или уменьшатся, и был активен тот этаж, у которого data атрибут с числом этажа, совпадал с числом в счетчике.

Я реализовал подобный функционал, но только при клике на сам этаж. (число в счетчике меняется в зависимости от этажа на который был произведен клик, и сделал выбраный этаж активным). Как сделать подобное при клике на стрелки вверх/вниз?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь, понятно что на jquery это проще сделать, но хочу понять как делать на чистом js, так как я только начал изучать язык.

Ссылка на проект: https://plupiks.github.io/melody-landing/.

```
const floors = document.querySelectorAll(".house-floor");
const floorCountNumb = document.querySelector(".hero--value");
const arrowUp = document.querySelector(".hero--arrow-up");
const arrowDown = document.querySelector(".hero--arrow-down");

// При клике на этаж
floors.forEach(e => {

  e.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var floorActive = e.target;

    floors.forEach(e => {
      e.classList.remove("house-img--active");
    })

    floorActive.classList.add("house-img--active");

    var floorCount = e.target.dataset.floor;
    floorCountNumb.textContent = floorCount;
  })
})

// При клике на стрелку вверх
arrowUp.addEventListener('click', () => {

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let parths = document.querySelectorAll('.house-floor');
```

// При клике на стрелку вверх

```
arrowUp.addEventListener('click', function() => {
let value = parseInt(floorCountNumb.innerHTML);

if (value != parths.lenght) {
parths[value-1].classList.remove('house-img--active');
value++;
floorCountNumb.innerHTML = value;
parths[value-1].classList.add('house-img--active');
}
})
```

// При клике на стрелку вниз

```
arrowDown.addEventListener('click', function() => {
let value = parseInt(floorCountNumb.innerHTML);

if (value != 0) {
parths[value-1].classList.remove('house-img--active');
value--;
floorCountNumb.innerHTML = value;
parths[value-1].classList.add('house-img--active');
}
})
```

p.s. Такой код я называю "огородом", из-за того, что две функции практически одинаковые. Для базового понимания сойдет, но для работы желательно написать 1, универсальную функцию. Вот можете на досуге подумать как из этих двух написать одну (молчаливую) функцию.

Comment: Тут правда есть одно но, нужно чтобы первый этаж был не 1 а 02, и небольшой баг, если этаж выбран мышкой то при выборе этажа стрелкой вверх остается 2 выбраных этажа. Но всеравно спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 1):

В идеале, наверно, написать как-то так. Надеюсь более или менее понятно описал принцип. Раз учитесь языку, учитесь сразу мыслить как программист, а не тупо изучение api языка.

```
const floors = document.querySelectorAll('.house-floor')
const floorCountNumb = document.querySelector('.hero--value')
const arrowUp = document.querySelector('.hero--arrow-up')
const arrowDown = document.querySelector('.hero--arrow-down')

const ACTIVE_CLASS = 'house-img--active'
let selectedFloor = null

const resetSelectedFloor = () => {
    floors.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove(ACTIVE_CLASS))
}

const setActiveFloor = (num) => {
    const floor = floors.find((el) => el.dataset.floor === num)
    floor.classList.add(ACTIVE_CLASS)
    displayFloor(num)
    selectedFloor = num
}

const displayFloor = (num) => {
    floorCountNumb.textContent = num
}

// При клике на этаж
/**
 * Реализация необходимого функционала делаится на две части: 
 * сброс текущего активного элемента и назначение нового. Логику конечно можно написать в лоб, 
 * но лучше сразу выделить абстракции и спрятать реализацию за ними. Это позволит мыслить на уровне
 * предметной области и не думать о технической части + станет удобно масштабировть или изменять
 * текущий код. В вашем случае, тот же функционал выполняют кнопки на странице. Также обратите внимание,
 * что я вынес активный этаж в отдельную переменную как состояние, что позволяет достаточно просто
 * переиспользовать функции. Без нее вам бы пришлось выцеплять активный этаж из DOM элемента при нажатии кнопок,
 * что породило бы как минимум одну дополнительную функцию с лишней абстракцией. Также все строки или числа, 
 * которые используются по несколько раз, лучше выделять в отдельные переменные. 
 * В строках можно ошибиться, а с числами иногда не сразу понятно, не зная контекста, что они обозначают.
 */
floors.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
        resetSelectedFloor()

        const floor = ev.target.dataset.floor

        setActiveFloor(floor)
    })
})

// При клике на стрелку вверх
arrowUp.addEventListener('click', () => {
    resetSelectedFloor()
    setActiveFloor(selectedFloor + 1)
})

arrowDown.addEventListener('click', () => {
    resetSelectedFloor()
    setActiveFloor(selectedFloor - 1)
})
```

Comment: Понял, учту) Спасибо

Comment: вообще, правильней даже resetSelectedFloor запихать в setActiveFloor, потому что выбор активного этажа всегда нуждается в сбросе текущего. А в слушателях будет сразу понятно, что делает код, потому что по сути эти две функции являются реализацией одного действия

Comment: @Vitaliy рад помочь

Comment: скрип почему-то выдал ошибку "floors.find is not a function"

Comment: @Vitaliy поменяйте на [...floors].find((el) => el.dataset.floor === num)

Comment: сделал но теперь ошибка в другом "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')", при клике на стрелки.